# Sentinel-3 scaling factor in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, scale, esa, sentinel-3

Does anybody know how to use the scaling factors from Google Earth Engine with [Sentinel-3 dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S3_OLCI#bands)?

The band values provided in `ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI"` by default (GEE, orange) are integers which are very close to the official band values from ESA's Copernicus Open Access Hub (S3, blue) (see figure). The GEE values seem to be the rounded ESA values, thus I assume the scaling factors should bring the decimal part. From my experience the decimal part can also be negative.

[image: S3 - official Sentinel-3 data (ESA), GEE - Sentinel-3 data from GEE]

Comment: @user2856 this leads to extremely incorrect radiance values that is why the question was asked

Answer (score -1):

In my experience I did not apply the scaling factor, it seems that without scaling it matches